# Ruby Tags in title="" in HTML

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to include a variable in a title tag on a link.

e.g.

```
<%= link_to @user.facebook_link, title: "Facebook" %>
```

So it would look like so:

```
<%= link_to @user.facebook_link, title: "<% @user.name %> on Facebook", target: '_blank' do %>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using interpolation within a string in ruby, use `#{...}` instead:

```
<%= link_to @user.facebook_link, title: "#{@user.name} on Facebook", target: '_blank' do %>
```